# Редактирование PDF файла

Tags: c#, pdf

У меня есть `pdf` файл с данными. Мне нужно в него добавить в верхней части каждого листа ссылку на файл.  Чтоб при клике на неё открывался файл на который она указывает. Искал в интернете информацию по `iTextSharp`, но он кажется может только создавать. Какой библиотекой это можно сделать ? Желательно чтоб эта библиотека была более менее документирована или c примерами или если можно кусок куда.

Comment: У iTextSharp имеется свой [git](https://github.com/itext). И там много примеров.

Answer (score 2):

IText также можно использовать для добавления содержимого в PDF-документы.
Однако редактирование документа (поиск/замена) не поддерживается большинством библиотек, поскольку PDF-документы просто не редактируются.

Последняя версия iText `7.1.x`, примеры можно найти на сайте https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-manipulating-existing-pdf

Это должно быть относительно легко (псевдо-код)

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DST));

Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Lorem Ipsum")
                .setFontColor(ColorConstants.DARK_GRAY)
                .setTextAlignment(alignment)
                .setFontSize(12f + RND.nextInt(5));

ParagraphRenderer renderer = (ParagraphRenderer) 
para.createRendererSubTree();

renderer.setParent(new DocumentRenderer(new Document(pdfDocument)));
renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(pageNumber, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h))));
renderer.draw(new DrawContext(pdfDocument, new PdfCanvas(pdfDocument.getPage(pageNumber), false), true /* tagging */));
```